# Cartthrob and Stripe integration

Tags: cartthrob, stripe

Just wondered if anyone has done anything with the payment gateway within Cartthrob to try and use the "Stripe Checkout" over building your own standard checkout page... love the look of its clean simple interface over the standard checkout pages we would normally create, and that I've done so far. Also been able to integrate the mobile side of this would be much nicer and I'm sure help conversion. Just curious to know if anyone has integrated this and how they got it looking and working and if its worth even looking into , or just sticking with building your own as i have done so far with this integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All sorted and integrated nicely, just used the default cartthob settings with some tweaks